# how can i do https request with c++ with winsock2

Tags: c++, web, https

i want make https requests instead of http, from client to server with POST method.
These are the steps i follow to make simple http requests:

1. open a socket.
2. conect to server by its domain name.
3. prepare the data for request.
4. send request and get server response.

however i can't find anything about how i can do https requests with winsock in c++.
i tried to change the http header from **HTTP/1.1** to **HTTS/1.1** but doesn't working.
Can someone help?

EDIT:
after some time i found a post that helped a bit but now it not even send the request. 
before i had this code:

```
SOCKADDR_IN sin;
    ZeroMemory(&sin, sizeof(sin));
    sin.sin_port = htons(PORT);
    sin.sin_family = AF_INET;
    memcpy(&sin.sin_addr.S_un.S_addr, host->h_addr_list[0], sizeof(sin.sin_addr.S_un.S_addr));

    //connect to server
    if (connect(sock, (const sockaddr*)&sin, sizeof(sin))) {
        return "error";
    }
```

and now i did this:

```
SOCKADDR_IN sin;
    ZeroMemory(&sin, sizeof(sin));
    sin.sin_port = htons(PORT);
    sin.sin_family = AF_INET;
    memcpy(&sin.sin_addr.S_un.S_addr, host->h_addr_list[0], sizeof(sin.sin_addr.S_un.S_addr));

    //connect to server
    if (connect(sock, (const sockaddr*)&sin, sizeof(sin))) {
        return "error";
    }

    bind(sock, (sockaddr*)&sin, sizeof(sin));
    listen(sock, 5);
    int addrLen;
    SOCKET newsock = accept(sock,(sockaddr*)&sin, &addrLen);
    char buffer[255];
    recv(newsock, buffer, 255, 0);
```

after this part i try to send the request:

```
if (!send(newsock, ssds.c_str(), strlen(ssds.c_str()), 0)) {
        return "error";
    }
```

before i had the "sock" as socket and worked, but with new socket it not send the data

Comment: You have to read about SSL encryption and decryption. Not a trivial task. But instead of implementing this by hand, you can use wininet instead.

Comment: ok thanks @armagedescu i use wininet now and everything seems working fine